# Как проверить длину строки с помощью регулярного выражения?

Tags: c#, .net, регулярные-выражения

Как этот код описать в регулярном выражении?

```
var str = "";

if(str.Length == 6 || str.Length == 9)
    return true;
else return false;
```

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, я имею в виду, что мне нужно при помощи регулярного выражения узнать, содержит ли строка именно 6 или именно 9 символов. Это возможно?

Comment: Избыточный код, видимо вы хотели написать так `return str.Length == 6 || str.Length == 9;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно так:

```
var str = "111111111";
var pattern = @"^(.{6}|.{9})$";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(str, pattern));
```

Answer (score 3):

Например можно [так](https://regex101.com/r/iDDhmo/2)

```
^.{6}(.{3})?$
```